# Dont set value in Form.Control

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a new form for save data.

I use this code

```
const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
const [newInfo, setNewInfo] = useState({
    name: ""
});

const handleChange = (event) => {
 const { name, value }=event.target.value;
 setNewInfo({
     ...newInfo,
     [name]: value
 });
    console.log(newInfo.name)
};
```

and in Form.Control

```
<Form noValidate validated={validated}>
   <Form.Group >
   <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
   <Form.Control required type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" value={newInfo.name}
                                            onChange={handleChange} />
   <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Please choose a name.</Form.Control.Feedback>
                                     </Form.Group>
   <Button onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)} variant="primary">Submit</Button>
  </Form>
```

When i type in input, run onchangehandle and `event.target.value` has value but dont set in input (input is empty) !!

when i change `const [newInfo, setNewInfo] = useState("");` and set a string for it, it is ok .

Answer (score 0):

***setNewInfo***() which is a setter is asynchronous, which means that at the time you console.log the state, it's not updated yet.

*You can use useEffect to track for changes of state.*

```
useEffect(() => {
       console.log(newInfo);
  },[newInfo.name);
```

Comment: when i type a char in input, run onchangehandler but input is empty!!! dont type any char in input

Comment: When you type a char,  console.log outputs the initial value of the state (newInfo.name) which is initially empty.  After typing the second char, you see the first char in onchangehandler's console.log method.

Comment: dont work for me. example: when i type 'a' in changeHandler ---> event.target.value='a' , after `setNewInfo` , dont set value and show empty in input

Comment: Don't you get console.log output in useEffect?

Comment: No, it is empty. dot set value in onchange